# Session if statement working on one page but not the other

Tags: php, session

Before we start, I'm a beginner. I'm sure it's a simple solution but just not for me.

I'm using a session so no one can't access an admin page unless they're an admin.

The code is:

```
if ( $_SESSION['admin'] != 1 ) {
$_SESSION['message'] = "You're not admin!";
header("location: ../error.php");    
}
```

Which works perfectly. regular users can't access it but admins can. BUT.

In my main cpanel I want to have a button linking to the admin panel that will only appear if the user is admin. I did the same piece of code:

```
if ( $_SESSION['admin'] != 1 ) {
echo '<a href="admin/index.php"><button class="butto button-bloc" name="admin"/>Admin Panel</button></a>';
}
```

Problem is, it seems like the button shows up whether the user is an admin or not and now I think that my code is just trying to make me blow my lid as I spent a full hour trying to find what the f-- is on the go.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm sure someone who's good with PHP will have it solved in under a minute lol

Comment: Have you checked that the you are getting the `$_SESSION['admin']` in the page where the button needs to display ?

Comment: first check the value of session on page where you have issue :
`print_r($_SESSION); `

Comment: Yes, It's returning [admin] => 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you have written is same for user who is admin and not an admin

Please check the condition

For having a button linking to the admin panel that will only appear if the user is admin.

```
if ( $_SESSION['admin'] == 1 ) { // you have written $_SESSION['admin'] != 1
echo '<a href="admin/index.php"><button class="butto button-bloc" name="admin"/>Admin Panel</button></a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. that worked.

If you don't mind. can you explain to me as to why == works but != don't? 

!= works on my actual admin panel. --- Nevermind, I now understand. I need sleep I think.

Comment: glad.. i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1 )) {
    echo '<a href="admin/index.php"><button class="butto button-bloc" name="admin"/>Admin Panel</button></a>';
}
```

This way the button will show when you set the `$_SESSION['admin']` and if it is `TRUE` (i.e. 1).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']) {
    if ( ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1) ) {
        echo '<a href="admin/index.php"><button class="butto button-bloc" name="admin"/>Admin Panel</button></a>';
    }
}
```